# how do I get a root path redirect to not respond to all requests in eclipse jetty?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, redirect, servlets, jetty

I have a jetty servlet set of pages all set up and working.

to get to the landing page, you have to enter the full url http://127.0.0.1/console/console.jsp

everything is fine for my context "console".

I wanted to add a handler for the root url, so I could just put in a host and it would redirect to the above url.

I got that working, except it seems that every request comes through my root path handler as well and it messes up all the other requests to the real jsp pages.

How do I keep it from doing that, or what do I do differently?

my web.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>console</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.console.Consoleservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>console</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/console</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.console.Redirectservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

slimmed down version of my redirect servlet...

```
public class Redirectservlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet
  {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Redirectservlet()
      {
        super();
      }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
      {
        try
          {
            String redirect_path = "http://127.0.0.1/console/console.jsp";
            response.sendRedirect(redirect_path);
          }
        catch (Exception e)
          {
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using welcome-files instead of your `RedirectServlet`, in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`...

```xml
<web-app ...>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>console/console.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  ... other entries
</web-app>
```

If that doesn't work, consider making that a `RedirectFilter` instead, and only sending a redirect if the `request.getRequestURI()` is only in a list of exact request URI string matches that should redirect.

Comment: okay, I tried the welcome file, it didn't work, not sure why. I could fight with it more, but I like the other idea better. So I can redirect on the path I'm looking for, but what to do in the other cases? my redirect servlet is still getting requests for the other context. I gotta think there's some preference ordering or something like that that I'm missing. Thanks for the help, by the way.

Comment: the more I think about it the more I like the welcome file idea. all I want to do is one redirect, I'll play with that more.

Comment: yeah the welcome file works, I was being an idiot. much simpler than what I was trying to do, thanks.